# basic program exercise but not showing right result

Tags: python

I have written a simple program in python to find the largest number from the list. my codes run fine my the result is wrong.

In my list, there are a total of 9 digits and 50 is the largest one but my program show 3 digits

```
numbers = [1, 3, 10, 13, 2, 4, 6, 50, 9]
max = numbers[0]
for number in numbers:
    if number > max:
        max = number
        print(max)
```

My answer was

```
3
10
13
50
```

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Maybe you're aware of this, but Python has a built-in `max` function that does this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code right now is printing its result whenever it finds a single number bigger than the biggest it saw before. You want it to only print the biggest in the entire list.

Only output the `max` after you have checked every value in the list.

```
numbers = [1, 3, 10, 13, 2, 4, 6, 50, 9]
max = numbers[0]
for number in numbers:
    if number > max:
        max = number
print(max)
```

Notice how the `print(max)` was moved to be outside the loop, after every number was checked.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment above, you can simply use built-in function [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) which can be applied to a list to print the largest number in the list.

```
numbers = [1, 3, 10, 13, 2, 4, 6, 50, 9]    
print(max(numbers))
# 50
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment but I want to practice for loop, and I have to do this by for loop. My codes give the output without error but not completing the task.

Comment: @TauqeerAhmad : Its not completing the task because your print statement is inside the loop. Print statement outside the loop gives you the right answer as mentioned in first answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you want the max number of a list you can simply use numpy's max function:

```
import numpy as np

numbers = [1, 3, 10, 13, 2, 4, 6, 50, 9]
max = np.max(numbers)

print(max)
```

Comment: Why use numpy (or any other external library) for this when Python itself has a built-in `max`?

Comment: That is a good point. This was the first thing I thought of to help the poster but you are right.

Comment: Thank all of you for your comment but I want to practice for loop, and I have to do this by for loop. My codes give the output without error but not completing the task please tell me where is the problem. ?